# How to generate QuestionnaireResponse using LHC-Forms (LForms)

Tags: javascript, hl7-fhir, smart-on-fhir

I'm working through the capabilities of LHC-Forms (LForms) in github here:

https://github.com/lhncbc/lforms-fhir-app

Looking at the example here:

https://lhcforms.nlm.nih.gov/sdc

There is a button that lets the user see a FHIR QuestionnaireResponse based on the form and the data entered in the form.  Using the debugging/Elements tool in my browser, the button has a javascript:void(0) method for href.  What does LForms use to generate the QuestionnaireResponse from the form displayed on the page?  Is this documented somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Documentation for LHC-Forms is at http://lhncbc.github.io/lforms/.  Following the "Exporting FHIR" link on the left (http://lhncbc.github.io/lforms/#retrieving-fhir-data), you will see it provides this API call for getting back a FHIR Resource:

```
LForms.Util.getFormFHIRData(resourceType, fhirVersion, formDataSource, options)
```

So, for an R4 QuestionnaireResponse, one could write:

```
LForms.Util.getFormFHIRData("QuestionnaireResponse", "R4")
```

Incidentally, questions about LHC-Forms are more likely to get noticed on the "questionnaire" stream at chat.fhir.org, or by posting an issue on the GitHub package (though sometimes I miss the notice about those).